# How to submit a button from a nowhere?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I am making a new Datatable and there is such functionality in it that I could [extend a row](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child.isShown()) if someone has pressed on it:

```
// Add event listener for opening and closing details
$('#datatable-buttons tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(){
    var tr = $(this);
    var row = a.row( this );


    if(row.child.isShown()){
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
           }
});
```

So, if someone has pressed on a button at an extended line than I could listen it:

```
$('#datatable-buttons tbody').on('click', 'td button', function(){
    var tr = $(this);
    var row = a.row( this );
```

However I have tried 100 ways to submit a form of this line and nothing works proper.

This is simple function which extends a row:

```
function format ( d ) {
    var editform = '<form> ... <button type="submit" class="btn 
    btn-primary mb-2" >Submit</button></div> </div></form>';

    return editform; 
}
```

So, now I could only listen to it when button is pressed but I don't know how to take this data and submit a form.

Once again: 1. Datatable have rows and doesn't have any buttons. 2. If you press on any one of the rows - it will extend and show it's details (new area below of the row will appear). 3. It is a form on this area. 4. I can't to submit it.

**UPDATE: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vs6qemh4/1/)** You can see an issue pressing any row and submitting a button. So you could have an alert but not the form data.

Comment: You can submit a form using the DOM function `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`. You will need to change your editform to include an id inside the form element:

`var editform = '<form id="myForm"> ... <button type="submit" class="btn 
    btn-primary mb-2" >Submit</button></div> </div></form>';`

Comment: it's not quite clear...you want to submit the form via code, without the user pressing the button, is that right? When exactly do you want this to occur? And what have you tried?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work this way. :(  There are no html code on a page from that form.

Comment: @ADyson 1. Datatable have rows and no any buttons. 2. If you press on any row - it will extends (new area below of the  row will appear). 3. It is a form on this area. 4. I can't to submit it.

Comment: <form> tags cannot be inside <table> tags. It won't show any specific error, but will not submit form at this level. You need to use on-click handler to submit the form.

Comment: "new area below of the row will appear" ...where exactly in the markup does the form get inserted? Please show us an example of the finished HTML after the insertion (you can use your browser's element inspector to see it). As mentioned by suketup, if the `<form>` tag is inside a `<table>` or `<tr>`, but not also within a `<td>` then it won't work properly. Tables can only contain rows, and rows can only contain cells. All other elements are not valid.

Comment: Have you considered use of the FormData interface?

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for a support. I have made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vs6qemh4/1/ You can see an issue pressing any row and submitting a button. So you could have an alert but no form data.

Comment: that code is different to what you showed in the question. Specifically, you've added this part: `action="javascript:alert( "success!" );"` to the submit button, and that's the problem. Have you checked your browser's console for errors when running that JSFiddle? You'll see a syntax error. Try `action="javascript:alert( \'success!;\' );"` instead. BTW, I assume you realise that setting the form's action to be JavaScript code will stop it sending any data to the server? Is that what you want?

Comment: @ADyson Wow. Indeed, it shows message. I wanted to make ajax request from some js function. So, now looks like I could simple add a new function and submit it with it, correct?

Comment: Modifying the action is not really the recommended way, to be honest. Better to add another click handler to handle the "submit" event of the forms. Like you do to handle the clicks on the table rows. e.g. `  $('#table_id tbody').on('submit', 'form', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault(); //...and then your AJAX code goes here`. You can just delete the form's "action" attribute, if you're going to use AJAX then you don't really need it. Also delete the form's id, since duplicate IDs are invalid in HTML, and you might add the form more than once. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/moa1nr9j/

Comment: @ADyson It really exactly what I was looking for. Could you please to make it as answer - it is really supportive!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your JSFiddle code and the comments, it seems you were trying to suppress the form submission with a view to using an AJAX request to submit the data instead. However, you'd done it by trying to modify the "action" attribute of the form tag, and in doing so introduced a syntax error.

Although you might be able to make this technique work, it's not the recommended way, and does have some drawbacks. It's better to handle the form's "submit" event using a standard jQuery (delegated) event handler:

```
$('#table_id tbody').on('submit', 'form', function(event) { 
  event.preventDefault(); 
  //...and then your AJAX code goes here
});
```

`event.preventDefault` will stop the regular form submission from happening, so that you can then run the AJAX code.

Here's an adapted version of your JSFiddle showing it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/moa1nr9j/

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your kind support! Wish you a luck in all of your projects and tasks.